# How do I access event handlers from resource dictionary file?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a resource dictionary file, in its .xaml.cs file I have an event handler like:

```
private static bool OnlyNumbersAllowed(string text)
       {
           Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
           return !regex.IsMatch(text);
       }

       private void PreviewTextInputHandlerInt(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
       {
           e.Handled = !OnlyNumbersAllowed(e.Text);
       }
```

While in the main window i want to access this code, like:

```
<TextBox Name="Par5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="357,36,0,0" Width="120" 
PreviewTextInput="{DynamicResource PreviewTextInputHandlerInt}"/>
```

Which won't work (the resource could not be resolved).
Also, I did some changes in dictionary root element, like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    x:Class="network_app.Resources.ResDictionary"
                    x:ClassModifier="public">
```

I have access to this event handler from many other windows in my project, that's why I don't want to copy the code of event handler all over these windows in code-behind. Is it possible somehow to access my event handler, declared in resource dictionary? Thanks.

Comment: Put the handler in a common (perhaps `static`) class...

Comment: Having `OnlyNumberAllowed` as `public` wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made this by adding this thing into resourcedictionary.xaml:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxInt">
    <TextBox PreviewTextInput="PreviewTextInputHandlerInt"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then I accessed this in main window xaml like this:

```
<TextBox Template="{StaticResource TextBoxInt}" Name="Par5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="357,36,0,0" Width="120" />
```